# White screen after quiz submit "Course" module

Tags: 6, wsod

I noticed after I began adding a number of nodes to my course. That now when a quiz is completed instead of seeing the results page, they get white screen my server is running fine. There are no errors in the logs with error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);

It works about 2 out of 10 times, the results page is shown.

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? If so, is there anything in syslog?

Comment: only have access to error log I am developing on pantheon platform getpantheon.com but the error log shows no errors.